# Store first result of where command into a variable and stop searching

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

I have a particular file on my C drive and I want to be able through a .bat script to search for that file and change the directory into the Folder containing this file.

What I have so far is to retrieve the search result into a variable :

```
    For /f %%i in <'where /R C:\ *testfile.jar'> do set RESULT=%%i
```

The issue is that the where command does not stop after finding the file as it continues to search through the whole C drive for other similar files. However, in this case i know that this file only exists once on my drive so how can I make the where command stop after finding the path ?

Comment: Not with `where.exe`. That's going to search and output a list of _all_ files matching the wildcard.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this question?

Comment: Not really, I ended up searching through a subfolder where I knew the (unique) file would be without knowing the exact path. The search was therefore pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to do this without searching the entire device before setting the variable is to use PowerShell. The cmd `FOR` loop will complete the command before it does the `DO` block. PowerShell pipes push the data through as it is found.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN (' ^
    powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
        "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Recurse -Filter '*testfile.jar' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |" ^
        "Select-Object -First 1 |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }" ^
    ') DO (
    SET "FN=%%~f"
)

ECHO "%FN%"
```